# Best translation of "I would be honoured": wäre or würde

Tags: english-to-german

I am trying to translate the following sentence:

> I would be very honoured to be part of the team.

My version:

> Es wäre mir eine große Ehre, Teil des Teams zu sein.

Should I use "Es wäre mir eine große Ehre" or better "Es würde eine große Ehre"?

Comment: _"Es würde eine große Ehre"_ No, at best _Es würde **mir** eine große Ehre **sein**_

Comment: The question is quite specifically about one word (wäre vs. würde). I don't agree that it falls under the "no proof reading" rule, I don't really see why it was closed.

Comment: @HalvarF, noch schlimmer finde ich die ungerechtfertigten Abwertungen.

Comment: Falls es sich um Bewerbung handelt entweder "Es wäre mir eine große Ehre, .." oder
 "Es wird mir eine große Ehre sein" je nachdem wie viel Selbstvertrauen dargestellt werden soll. "Es würde mir eine große Ehre sein " hat jedenfalls einen unterton von _... aber ich halte das für unwahrscheinlich_

Answer (score 6):

Hier geht es um die verschiedenen Modi des Verbs [*sein*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:sein#Indikativ_und_Konjunktiv). Im Indikativ (Präsens) lautet der Satz:

> Es *ist* mir eine große Ehre.

Konjunktiv I und II lauteten:

> Es *sei* mir eine große Ehre.
>
> Es *wäre* mir eine große Ehre.

Der Konjunktiv II kann auch in der Ersatzform mit *würde* ausgedrückt werden:

> Es *würde* mir eine große Ehre *sein*.

In diesem recht kurzen Satz ist die Ersatzform nicht idiomatisch; man findet sie aber, vor allem in der gesprochenen Sprache, in längeren Sätzen, besonders in Bedingungssätzen:

> Es *würde* mir ja eine große Ehre *sein*, aber gestern, da hast du mich nun mal so enttäuscht, dass …

Comment: Also possible and idiomatic: *Ich würde mich sehr geehrt fühlen*.